# SSH (password less authentication) to server/machine from docker container?

Tags: docker, server, dockerfile, docker-machine

Please find the steps I have tried for this task ( by the way - I am new to this concept) :

> installed Docker in Ubuntu
>
> docker pull ubuntu image
>
> Used docker run -it to create a container
>
> Checked the server response ( ping -c 4 ) and working fine.

Now I need help/idea to created a password less authentication btw server and container.

Container - root permissions

Server - username : ramparn , server : 173.33.255.20

I found the below link from docker forums but not helpful.

could you please help me here if you are aware of this task? or done before

Answer (score 0):

You can go inside running docker container by using below command.

```
docker exec -i -t ubuntu_container_name bash
```

Hope this will help you or can you please share your dockerfile?

Comment: Nope. Here I am trying manually.

With the given command I entered to the running container.
May I know what to be done now to enable SSH connection to the server from container?

Comment: I got how to link between containers. 
Example : -
container 1 : docker run -d --name <name of the image> <image> or run container if you have already a downloaded image

container 2 : docker run --link 

here --link creates the linking between containers. 

do we have anyother way like this to get same for container to local server?